# read() system call doesn't fail when an alarm signal is received

Tags: c, macos, signals, alarm, system-calls

This is (part of) my server-side code

```
void timeout_handler(int value) {
    printf("Handler\n");
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    [...]
    signal(SIGALRM, timeout_handler);
    alarm(seconds);
    int result = read(input_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (result == -1 && errno == EINTR) {
        printf("read() failed\n");
    }
    [...]
}
```

where `input_socket` is a TCP socket correctly connected with a client (if I send data from the client, the server receives them).

As a test of the alarm signal, I tried just to open and connect the socket client-side without send any data.
I would expect an output like

```
Handler
read() failed
```

but the result is only the `Handler` message, and then the process is still active.

Why the `read()` doesn't fail with `errno=EINTR`?

Comment: Note: You should not call printf() (and friends) from within a signal handler; they are not async-safe.

Comment: Why would the `read()` fail? It is waiting for something to come up. `If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until data is available.`

Comment: On which OS do you observe this behaviour? BSD?

Comment: The use of `printf` is just for testing purpose. And I thought the `read()` would have failed because the process receives an interrupting signal (the `alarm(seconds)`), and the signals interrupt slow system calls. I'm developing on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also on OSX certain system calls are *restarted by default* when having been interupted by a signal.

`siginterrupt()` can be used to change this behaviour. The following line (somewhere before `alarm()` is called) should do the job to let the program behave as expected by the OP:

```
siginterrupt(SIGALRM, 1);
```

---

From the OSX documentation (emphasis by me):

> For some system calls, if a signal is caught while the call is executing and the call is prematurely
>        terminated, the call is automatically restarted.  **Any handler installed with signal(3) will have the
>        SA_RESTART flag set**, meaning that any restartable system call will not return on receipt of a signal.
>        The affected system calls include **read(2)**, write(2), sendto(2), recvfrom(2), sendmsg(2), and recvmsg(2)
>        on a communications channel or a low speed device and during a ioctl(2) or wait(2).  However, calls
>        that have already committed are not restarted, but instead return a partial success (for example, a
>        short read count).  These semantics could be changed with siginterrupt(3).

This is different on Linux for example, where restarting of system call possibly interupted needs to explicitly be requested by the signal sent.

Comment: BTW: linux mostly emulates the BSD behaviour, depending on the libc version and _BSD_SOURCE and/or _GNU_SOURCE being defined. (better use sigaction anyway ...)

Comment: Thank you! This works! But also the use of `sigaction()` (instead of `signal()`) with `sa_flags = 0` solves the problem!

Comment: @JustTrying: I guessed this, but wasn't sure and couldn't test it.

Comment: @wildplasser: +1 also for `sigaction()` :-)